# Speeding up SQL query with index on identity column or the searched column?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

When I extract my table I get this. The table has an `ID` column which is an identity column (autoinc).

Then there is still the readable Customer number which is theoretically unique, but the table does not enforce anything so far.

My customers are searching for the customer number not the Id.

My question now: should I still add an index (if yes clustered/nonclustered?) to the `CUSTERMERNUMBER` column to increase the speed of the search?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTOMERNUMBER] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    -- other columns  

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                         IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                         ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Yes an index would help. But you can't have it clustered as your primary key is already the clustered index. Do you really need to use nvarchar here? Are you planning on having characters outside of the ascii character set as part of your customer number?

Comment: The customernumber is just "345345453543534" no alphabetical chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ID` field is referenced in other tables as a foreign key then leave that as the clustered index for sure, and create a non-clustered index on `CUSTOMERNUMBER`.

Consider not *just* creating an index on `CUSTOMERNUMBER` but going further and creating a `Unique Constraint` on it (which comes with an index). This will prevent the business rule requiring unique `CUSTOMERNUMBER` from being violated, and also gives additional information to the database that it can use to make operations more efficient.

As always, test first:

```
Alter Table Customer Add Constraint uCUSTOMERNUMBER Unique (CUSTOMERNUMBER);
```

(A downside of a unique constraint is that the unique index it creates can't `include` additional columns. If having includes was a requirement then a unique, non-clustered index is an option.)

Comment: Well enforcing the customer number to be unique is a good thing. I do not need additional columns to be unique together with the customer number.

Answer (score 1):

If the majority of searches on your table are being done on the Customer Number, it might be a great idea. You can also create several test queries before you create your index and run the queries on your index again after you create your index to see if the Index actually increases your performance.

When deciding if you should make the index clustered or non-clustered, you should determine if you already have a clustered index (because they are created automatically on the primary key) and if this new index would be better utilized as the primary key. If so, you may have to create some constraints so customer number has to be unique to guarantee search correctness.

If you are interested in learning more about indexes, feel free to checkout this article I wrote:
https://dataschool.com/learn/how-indexing-works

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Unique/Non Clustered index on customer number is a good idea .But we should be careful as to not create too many indexes especially if the table is huge with lots of DML s happening .